# How to execute shell commands synchronously in PHP

Tags: php, shell

I need to run multiple scripts(5 scripts) via cmd, I want to make sure unless and until the first script finishes the second should not initiate. Thus after first script completes then only second should being then third one and so on..
Currently I am using the following code to do this

```
exec ("php phpscript1.php ");
exec ("php phpscript2.php ");
exec ("php phpscript3.php ");
exec ("php phpscript4.php ");
exec ("php phpscript5.php ");
```

I think these scripts run asynchronously, any suggestion guys so that these scripts can be run synchronously.

Comment: When you say 'via cmd', do you mean using the Windows command prompt, or are you using a shell like bash, sh, zsh, etc?

Comment: I'm pretty certain that they're not running *asynchronously* at the moment, on the contrary. They run one after the other, which is called "synchronous".

Comment: *which* shell are you using? Just saying "shell" tells me next to nothing.

Comment: You are probably looking for [php running multiple shell scripts in background](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20running%20multiple%20shell%20scripts%20in%20background). Then use `&` for that.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

PHP [exec](http://php.net/manual/function.exec.php) will wait until the execution of the called program is finished, before processing the next line, unless you use & at the end of the string to run the program in background.

Comment: You saved me from doing a needless experiment, and I salute you.

Comment: @stivlo: same here, thanks bro.Just want to ask what if command is executed from different client, e.g. I want to stop exec until first one finished, if it is fired from 2 client PC simultaneously.(my exec running some other hardware program which does not support parallel execution)

Answer (score 9):

If I'm getting you right, you're executing php scripts from inside a php script.

Normally, php waits for the execution of the `exec ("php phpscript1.php");` to finish before processing the next line.

To avoid this, just redirect the output to `/dev/null` or a file and run it in background.

For example: `exec ("php phpscript1.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &");`.

Comment: @Bill'o: Your edit is invalid. Your code passes `/dev/null` as an argument to the PHP script, but it doesn't perform redirection.

Comment: indeed my mistake, i typed a bit too fast

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function syntax on php.net.
You will see that `exec` does not run anything asynchronously by default.

`exec` has two other parameters. The third one, `return_var` can give you a hint if the script ran successfully or any exception was fired. You can use that variable to check if you can run the succeeding scripts.

Test it and let us know if it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, it would be better to run cronjobs. They will execute synchronously. If the task is "on-the-fly", you could execute the command to add this cronjob. More information about cronjobs:
http://unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html

http://service.futurequest.net/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=30

Answer (score 2):

Both exec and system wait for the script to execute unless you don't fork.

Check.php

```
<?php
    echo "here ".__LINE__."\n";
    exec ("php phpscript1.php");
    echo "here ".__LINE__."\n";
    system("php phpscript2.php");
    echo "here ".__LINE__."\n";
?>
```

phpscript1.php

```
<?php
echo "=================phpscript1.php\n";
sleep(5);
?>
```

phpscript2.php

```
 <?php
    echo "=================phpscript2.php\n";
    sleep(5);
    ?>
```

Check.php execute script1 for 5 seconds then display next line number and then execute script2 by printing the next line.