# php exec() and shell_exec()

Tags: php

I currently have a php page that my webserver serves. In order to display all the information I need to display on the page I need output from an external python script. So I have been using the exec() command of php to execute the python script and capture the output in an array of strings as follows:

```
$somequery = $_GET['query'];
$result = exec("python /var/www/html/query/myscript.py ".somequery."");

//some for loop to loop through entries in result and echo them.
```

However there are never any entries to be printed, yet when I run the command directly on the console of the server it will output correctly. I've tried echoing out the command on the webpage that I am executing and it's the correct command. The only thing I think it can be is that exec() doesn't stop the rest of the php program from executing before it finishes, leading to the loop i have printing out entries finding that $result is empty.

How can I ensure that exec() finishes executing before the rest of my php script? Are there maybe settings in php.ini that I would need to change? I'm not entirely sure.

EDIT: I've tried running and storing the output of shell_exec("echo hello"); and printing that output, it now prints. However, when running my command that takes a few seconds longer, the program never finishes executing it before going to the next line.

EDIT 2: I found my solution in the following post https://stackoverflow.com/a/6769624 My issue was with with the numpy python package I was using and I simply needed to comment out the line in /usr/lib64/python2.7/ctypes/**init**.py like the poster did and my script output correctly.

Comment: This has already been [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621348/how-to-execute-shell-commands-synchronously-in-php)

Comment: FYI, that's completely insecure.  Anyone can run anything that your web server user has access to.  Be very careful with `exec()`.

Comment: It may have been asked, but none of those answers answer my question.

I also am aware this insecure, this isn't for a production environment however.. just a proof of concept.

Comment: php exec always wait the finish

Comment: i think you need to use full path to python binary  like `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: @eicto I just tried that, there doesn't seem to be any difference.

Comment: run `system("/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/query/myscript.py ".somequery." 2>&1");` and check the output, here should be error

Comment: array(10) { [0]=> string(34) "Traceback (most recent call last):" [1]=> string(74) " File "/var/www/html/Collaboratum/query/lsiquery.py", line 1, in " [2]=> string(27) " from numpy import zeros" [3]=> string(84) " File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 154, in " [4]=> string(20) " import ctypeslib" [5]=> string(84) " File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/ctypeslib.py", line 60, in " [6]=> string(17) " import ctypes" [7]=> string(71) " File

Comment: "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 549, in " [8]=> string(34) " CFUNCTYPE(c_int)(lambda: None)" [9]=> string(11) "MemoryError" } Array @eicto this is the error output, it seems it's running out of memory? I'm not sure. But when I actually run the command the program executes and outputs correctly.

Comment: the process probably out of ulimit,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6769624 I found a solution here. The underlying problem was with the numpy package I was using in my script. I simply commented out the line in /usr/lib64/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py that the poster I linked did and my script executed and output correctly. Thank you for all of your help @eicto

Comment: Both these functions are dangerous and should be turned off in your php configuration. Using them is almost never a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to get your shell output is like this:

```
exec("python /var/www/html/query/myscript.py ".somequery."", $result);

var_dump($result); //output should be in here
```

Give it a try.

Comment: On a side note: putting the $_GET value directly into your exec() command without any sanitization is VERY dangerous. Easy example, if someone inserts $_GET['query'] as ` && rm -rf /` (DO NOT attempt to try this), you just got your whole server deleted. Be sure to run it through some kind of sanitization.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php I use this when I'm actually running it on an accessible server. 

Also, I did a var_dump after running it your way and I simply get array(0) {}