# Is exec async or sync?

Tags: php, synchronization, exec

I am trying to figure out why my script doesn't wait until the completion of this command before moving on to the next thing.

```
exec('env MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT=1; convert -density 72 '.$tempPath.'/'.$row['tempFile'].' -resize 25% '.$tempPath.'/thumbs/%03d.png');
```

A nice follow-up question is, if synchronously is possible, how can I make it so this completes then the next thing in my script (in this case a database update), runs then and only then. Bonus if I can determie if `exec()` caused an error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute shell commands synchronously in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621348/how-to-execute-shell-commands-synchronously-in-php)